# Breaking up Expectation over a Joint Distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value

For some distribution $D\in \Delta(\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y} )$ and function $f : \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y} \to \mathbb{R}$, is it true that:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_{(x,y)\sim D} [f(x,y)] = \mathbb{E}_{x} [\mathbb{E}_y[f(x,y)\, |\, x]].
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the [Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).